# Creating a canvas cursor, unable to store color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cursor, html5-canvas

After trying many different things I have finally gotten a cursor to resize upon entry of a canvas but can't figure out how to save the color.

My mouse is based off of this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/XcjX9/

```
function loop() {
    var color = 'rgb(' + ((255 * Math.random())|0) + ','
                       + ((255 * Math.random())|0) + ','
                       + ((255 * Math.random())|0) + ')';
    makeCursor(color);
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

function makeCursor(color) {

    var cursor = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = cursor.getContext('2d');

    cursor.width = 16;
    cursor.height = 16;

    ctx.strokeStyle = color;

    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    ctx.moveTo(2, 12);
    ctx.lineTo(2, 2);
    ctx.lineTo(12, 2);
    ctx.moveTo(2, 2);
    ctx.lineTo(30, 30)    
    ctx.stroke();

    document.body.style.cursor = 'url(' + cursor.toDataURL() + '), auto';
}
```

Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Vw4yD/

```
function init(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
    elemTop = elem.offsetTop,
    context = elem.getContext('2d'),
    elements = [];

    //Spawn mouse on canvas enter.
    elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        makeCursor();
    });

    //Destroy mouse on canvas exit.
    elem.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    });

    // Add event listener for `click` events.
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
            y = event.pageY - elemTop;

        var brushHeight = document.getElementById('brushHeight').value;
        var brushWidth = document.getElementById('brushWidth').value;
        var brushColor = document.getElementById('brushColor').value;

        // Render elements.
        elements.forEach(function(element) {
            //Listen for controls.
            context.fillStyle = brushColor;
            context.fillRect(x, y, brushWidth, brushHeight);
        });
        // Add element.
        elements.push({
            colour: brushColor,
            width: brushWidth,
            height: brushHeight,
        });
    }, false);

    //Draw Mouse.
    function makeCursor() {
        var cursor = document.createElement('canvas'),
            cursorctx = cursor.getContext('2d');

        var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
            y = event.pageY - elemTop;

        var cursorLeft = cursor.offsetLeft;
            cursorRight = cursor.offsetTop;

        var brushHeight = document.getElementById('brushHeight').value;
        var brushWidth = document.getElementById('brushWidth').value;
        var brushColor = document.getElementById('brushColor').value;

        cursor.width = brushWidth;
        cursor.height = brushHeight;

        cursorctx.fillStyle = brushColor;
        cursorctx.fillRect(x, y, brushWidth, brushHeight);
        cursorctx.fill();

        document.body.style.cursor = 'url(' + cursor.toDataURL() + '), auto';
    }
};
```

The mouse is supposed to resize (which it does) and change color when entering the canvas, is there anyway you guys know of to get this to work? It has me stumped, I've worked on it for about a full day now and can't find anyway of doing it using rectangles, stroking works but is too complicated for the basic stuff I need done. Sorry if this post is poorly written, I've had very little sleep in the past day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Vw4yD/1/

I've removed the `x` and `y` for the cursor. They should be equal to 0, because it's relative to the cursor canvas, not the main canvas.

Comment: TYVM! Don't know why I added that in the first place.